# Set height for item in RecycleView

Tags: android

I have a RecycleView with layout vertical, with each item I set `height = "wrap_content"`. But each item such as code below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/name_fee_linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/zpw_item_listview_padding_left_right"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_imageview"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/zpw_item_listview_padding_top_bottom"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/zpw_item_listview_padding_top_bottom">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/zpw_text_size_medium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_grey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/zpw_text_size_medium_small" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So, when the item does not have @+id/subtitle_textview not have the description, this item will have height small than item has the description on subtitle_textview.

The solution I want all item to have the same height in Recycle View by set height all item = height of item have height highest in list item Please help me with this problem.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `minHeight` you dont want to set the max height of each row

Comment: Can you please state why you need all the heights to be equal to maximal height element? Is there any known maximal height (then height or minHeight will do)? Asking this because it does not seem very good UI solutions - can you tell more about what you have and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to say is you want some fixed height of that perticular view even if it doesn't contain any text.

Perheps you can use "Android:minHeight" and set it's value to whatever height you want. Let me know if I'm correct about it or not.